# How to load a view with ajax with all js files needed?

Tags: 7, views, ajax, comments, rating

I am using this function to load three views which are loading comments of a node in three tabs by three different sort types by ajax:

```
function sort1(){
var nid='<?php echo $node->nid; ?>';    
$.ajax({
    url: 'http://www.example.com/views/ajax',
    type: 'post',
    data: {
        view_name: 'comments_views',
        view_display_id: 'block_3', 
        view_args: nid,
    },
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function(response){
        $('#cm').html(response[1].data);
    }
});
    return false;   
}
```

And for other two views there exist a similar function.

Now what is the problem?

These comments can be replied and voted. But after switching between tabs nether reply nor vote works by ajax. I am using ajax_comment module in order to make it work by ajax and voteAPI and Rate module for rating comments.

I think views is failing in loading js of views.

what is the solution?

Comment: where do you put this js snippet? I think it's because the position of your codes. please provide more details.

Comment: Are there any errors in the JavaScript console?

Comment: @zhilevan I put it in a block and print views in the same block by this code print views_embed_view('myviews', 'block_3');

Comment: @Neograph734 nop

Comment: This isn't working because one, you are trying to do an echo statement for no reason and two, you are accessing an object that doesn't exist. Function sort1 takes no arguments yet you reference `$node` which your function has no idea about. You need to either pass the $node, or fetch it with `$node = menu_get_object('node');` - is this in a PHP file or Javascript file? I can't tell. Not enough information here to even help.

Answer (score 0):

What you did is a HardCode solution ,I suggest you instead of loading JS on block, put your JS in `.JS` files and add ( or attached) to page you want, with simple if your JavaScript just works for you, and remain only one problem, how pass NID to JS?

Pass it with something like

```
drupal_add_js(array('YOURMODULE' => array('nid' => $nid)), array('type' => 'setting'));
```

and get it on your js with

```
nid = Drupal.settings.YOURMODULE.nid;
```

1
down vote

There is a lot of documentation about how to include a JS file into a custom module or into your theme in general. Here is the official article: https://www.drupal.org/node/304255

There are plenty of examples and you can inspire yourself with it.